# Getting only one dimension of indexes from the getSelectedIndexes function in QT?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, indexing, pyqt4

I'm working on a small project in QT (well, pyQT4 actually, but it shouldn't matter too much) and I've run into the following problem. I have a `QTableView` with several rows and columns. I have set the selection mode to be rows only. When I call `getSelectedIndexes()` on my `QTableView`, I get an index for every row and column, which in the current setup means that I get an extra 5 Indexes for each selected row, which is less than ideal, since I only need to know the row, not the column. Is there any way to get just one Index per row other than filtering the list that I get from `getSelectedIndexes()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selection is maintained by `QItemSelectionModel`, which provides a method called [`selectedRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) that does what you want. For example:

```
myTableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows()
```